# what benefit does the UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF profile have over RTP/SAVPF?

Tags: webrtc, sdp

From this [PSA - Chrome 46 will use "UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF" profile instead of "RTP/SAVPF"](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/discuss-webrtc/ZOjSMolpP40)

What benefit does the new profile have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

more people at the IETF agree this is the correct thing to do in SDP. That's about it